# NSDate ivar become <not an Objective-C object>?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
   dueDate = [NSDate date];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    self.lbDueDate.text = [formatter stringFromDate:dueDate];
}
```

In init method I declared dueDate = [NSDate date]. But when I debug, at this line

```
    self.lbDueDate.text = [formatter stringFromDate:dueDate];
```

And Output: (NSDate *) dueDate = 0x0c497390 
So what happend ?

Comment: This can happen when an object isn't properly retained, is this an ARC project?  If its not ARC you should use `dueDate = [[NSDate date] retain];`

Comment: Declare `dueDate` as @property and use `self.dueDate` instead of `dueDate`. That should fix it in ARC/non-ARC.

Comment: and @property should be retain/strong (non-ARC/ARC)...

Comment: Can you explain me why if use self.dueDate instead of dueDate the problem is fixed ? What diff between ivar and property in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

It means the object's been `-dealloc`ed (unless it is `nil`). So run with Zombies and message it more often -- after running the static analyzer and reviewing your code.

one problem in the source: `dueDate = [NSDate date];` should be `dueDate = [[NSDate date] copy];`. another problem is that you don't call through the superclass' designated initializer in your implementation of `-initWithCoder:`.

Comment: Why need to call through the superclass' designated initializer ?

Comment: @DungProton you call it in `-initWithCoder:` because `-initWithCoder:` is an initializer. same as any initializer implementation (i.e. `-init`). so you would write `self = [super initWithCoder:pCoder]` if the superclass adopts `NSCoding`, otherwise use an appropriate designated initializer (`self = [super init]` is common). without that step, you should assume the base class(es) are not properly initialized.

Comment: I just know I must write `self = [super initWithCoder:pCoder]` but I really really don't know why I have to do that. Can you share me any documents or posts related this.

Thank you very very much ^^

Comment: @DungProton basic initialization/destruction symmetry. it's covered in the relevant guide; *Archives and Serializations Programming Guide*. Two reasons: a) so the base can also deserialize any information/state it has serialized, and b) because the base class' implementation may return an allocation other than the one passed as the named implicit parameter `self`. this means that serializing the subclass' state is the responsibility of the subclass (good); if you override the superclass' implementation you must call the proper initializer so the superclass can also deserialize itself correctly

Comment: (cont) and again, you would just go through one of the designated initializers in your implementation of `-initWithCoder:` if your class is the first to adopt `NSCoding`.