# NSDate not an Objective-C object?

Tags: ios, nsdate

This is one of those questions that is so absurdly simple that I can't believe I'm asking it on here.  But, I'm stumped, so here I go: I'm trying to create an `NSDate` for a certain time in the future.  I thought it was easy, but when I try:

```
NSDate *destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30];
```

a breakpoint at the following line says that `destinationDate` is "not an Objective-C object."  I tried a million different versions, from this:

```
NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30];
```

to this:

```
NSDate *destinationDate = [NSDate date];
```

to this (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049971/nsdate-ivar-become-not-an-objective-c-object)):

```
NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate date] copy];
```

And nothing works!  They're all "not Objective-C objects"!  I'm sure it's something simple and embarrassing that I'm missing, but I am completely at a loss.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: Show the exact text of the following line, and the exact error message you're getting (it's not a "breakpoint").

Comment: The next line is unrelated (it's `NSLog(@"Set");`), and it IS a breakpoint: I'm not getting an error message at all, I'm saying I set a breakpoint at the `NSLog` line and checked the value of `destinationDate`, which is listed as `destinationDate = (NSDate *) 0x14dc4100 <not an Objective-C object>`

Comment: What, exactly, says that's it's not an Objective-C object? The variables pane of the debugger? Printing the object with the `po` command? Something else? Which debugger are you using? Which version of iOS? Simulator or device? Are you putting the breakpoint at that exact line (in which case, no assignment will have been made to `destinationDate` yet, breakpoints stop prior to executing that line) or are you still getting it after stepping over that line?

Comment: if you dont use ARC all your setters did set autoreleased object

Comment: The variables pane of the debugger in XCode, with the breakpoint set at the following line (the NSLog line mentioned in the comment above), on a device, and I'm using ARC.

Comment: And that's the only issue? Your code doesn't crash or anything when accessing the date? If so I'd guess this is a debugger bug. I've seen this before intermittently, and I seem to recall it never reflected the state of the program and would stop happening after restarting Xcode or something.

Comment: I had no idea that was even a thing... Wow, yeah, I just NSLog'd the variable and it has data in there.  Well, if you post this as an answer I'll accept it and upvote, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can see in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that NSDate is indeed a NSObject, which ofcourse is a Objective-C object.

This is probably a bug of the debugger panel, unfortunately it happens a lot. When this weird things happens, always use the console, when in a breakpoint, with a `po myVariable` to check the content of your variable, it's more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

NSDate is a subclass of NSObject as per apple's documentation.

The methods you listed (alloc/init, and class method dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:) are valid uses.

It's hard to say more about it without knowing what your actual issue is, but if you are not using ARC, you might check that you retain/release correctly.

Comment: I am using ARC, and as for my specific issue: I get no error message or warning, but when I set a breakpoint at the line just after the one I listed and check the value of `destinationDate`, it's listed as `destinationDate = (NSDate *) 0x14dc4100 <not an Objective-C object>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the variable *after* the breakpoint as well? Otherwise the object might already be released by the time you hit the breakpoint, because the app doesn't need it anymore. Then you'll get a "not an object" message.

Comment: Yes, two lines later I add the variable to an array.

Comment: Did you try "po destinationDate" as command in the debugger? I found that sometimes the variables pane is not showing what the app is thinking, while the "po ..." command will show things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is Foundation not included in the project?

```
#include <Foundation/foundation.h>
```